# How can I remove brackets () in python List

Tags: python

I have a list :

```
listA = [('xxx@gmail.com\n',), ('111@gmail.com\n',)]
```

What i trying achieved is to remove the `()` and `\n` in each list's item.

Expected Output:

```
listA = ['xxx@gmail.com', '111@gmail.com',]
```

I did my researched but every articles online is about removing the square bracket but not （）

Answer (score 3):

The problem is the comma, not the brackets: `('a',)` is a `tuple`, while `('a') == 'a'`. Just get the item inside each tuple (I throw in some `strip`ping as well because you have `\n`s in the input and not in the expected output):

```
listA = [t[0].strip() for t in listA]
```

Comment: This returns `['x', '1']`

Comment: @RohithNambiar No it does not. Make sure you run it only once.

Comment: Oh sorry it works now